# custom cc 16 bits with Polynomial and Initial Value , algorithm

Tags: algorithm-analysis, polynomials, crc

I generate crc 16 bits with hex Workshop.

Polynomial :1234(hex)  Initial Value :5678 (hex) . making it on 010 (ascii) and get 3744.

[image]

I looking for this algorithm , I prefer it on c#. but I not find it.

Can you please help me?

thank you a lot!

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on this site.

Comment: I not recommend on software , I looking for algorithm